# Adding new element to nested classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to use JS to create a new element within specific nested classes in HTML. So in this example, I need to create a new span with the class of "paw-print" only where the "collies" class is nested within "dogs".

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/p50e228w/6/

The problem is that my current JS works on the first instance, but not on the other. I currently have `document.getElementsByClassName` set to "collies" but I need to target that class only when it's inside the parent "dogs" class.

What am I missing here?

```
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "paw-print";
var wrap = document.getElementsByClassName("collies");
for(var i = 0; i < wrap.length; i++) {
  wrap[i].appendChild(span);
}
```

I can use jQuery, but I've been using vanilla JS just because I'm such a noob and want to understand what my code is doing.

Comment: The issue is with your `absolute` positioning in CSS, not javascript

Comment: I fixed the CSS to make it more accurate. Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p50e228w/3/ ...But, if it were just the positioning, wouldn't I have more than one span?

Comment: The issue with [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) is that it doesn't _clone_ the element. If you reference an existing span, it just moves it to the new location in the document. That's why your end result only has 1 span.

Comment: As well as the appendChild issue, if you want to find only 'collies' that have a 'dogs' parent you should look into document.querySelectorAll rather than document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Ah. I stumbled across that in my searches, but couldn't figure out how to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code.

- Positioning : The images are being given a absolute position, and they rest in the same position based on the page layout. So set relative positioning for the parent container.

**CSS**

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

- You need to append that to parent element which is `collie` here.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to find the nested relation ship that you are looking for.

```
 var collies = document.querySelectorAll('.dogs .collies');
 for (var i = 0; i < collies.length; i++) {
   var span = document.createElement("span");
   span.className = "paw-print";
   collies[i].appendChild(span);
 }
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p50e228w/5/)**

Comment: @crezaii Glad to have helped !

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append to parent ( element with class 'dog')

```
$('.dogs .collies').each(function()  // finds elements in the dom with parent element 'dog' and it's child element 'collies'
{
  $(this) // 'this' would represent 'collies' element
 .closest('.dogs') //  .closest('.dogs') would get it's nearest occurence in the heirarchy ( basically it's parent )
 .append($('<span/>', { class: 'paw-print'})); // create a dynamic span element and append to 'this' 
});
```

If you want to append to child( element with class 'collies')

```
$('.dogs .collies').each(function()
{
  $(this).append($('<span/>', { class: 'paw-print'}));
});
```

In addition to this, you also need to set `position: relative` as pointed out by Rob.

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1zxn8193/1/

Comment: You need to make the parent div relative positioned for this to work, see: https://jsfiddle.net/1zxn8193/